# Cypress can't set local storage

Tags: local-storage, cypress

It seems I can't set local storage in Cypress?

When I get the item from local storage it is different to what I have set (it always returns the default value)

Am I setting the storage incorrectly?

```javascript
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.clearLocalStorage();
    cy.clearCookies();
    window.localStorage.setItem('One', 'NL');
    window.localStorage.setItem('Two', 'NL');
    window.localStorage.setItem('Three', 'NL');
    visitPage('/');

    cy.window().then((win) => {
      const myItemOne = win.localStorage.getItem('One');
      const myItemTwo = win.localStorage.getItem('Two');
      const myItemThree = win.localStorage.getItem('Three');
      cy.log(myItemOne, myItemTwo, myItemThree);
    });
```

Should return log NL, NL, NL, but logs SE, SV, SV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting local storage variables via `window.localStorage.setItem()` is a synchronous command, whereas your Cypress commands (such as `cy.clearLocalStorage()`) are asynchronous. This means that they probably are not executing in the order you write them. If you wrap setting your localStorage items within the Cypress command chain, they should be set appropriately.

```js
cy.clearLocalStorage();
cy.clearCookies();
cy.window().then((win) => {
  win.localStorage.setItem('One', 'NL');
  win.localStorage.setItem('Two', 'NL');
  win.localStorage.setItem('Three', 'NL');
});
visitPage('/');
```

Comment: I'd say it's a little misleading to call them asynchronous.  They're executed synchronously, but last after all the commands are called and queued up.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77256895/1108305

Comment: Cypress' own documentation describes them as asynchronous -> "Cypress commands are asynchronous and get queued for execution at a later time." https://learn.cypress.io/cypress-fundamentals/understanding-the-asynchronous-nature-of-cypress#understanding-the-asynchronous-nature-of-cypress (Not trying to debate if Cypress is correct in calling then asynchronous, just explaining my rationale behind describing them as such. As long as they call them asynchronous, I will too.)

Comment: Fair enough; was unaware of that.  They certainly have a clear, well-defined execution order relative to themselves and the other statements executed within the test file.  So it's definitely less loosey-goosey than I'd say most so-called "asynchronous" code.  But yeah, if that's how they're referring to it, makes sense to do likewise.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely understand that. It's some weird hybrid of Bluebird's Promise chain (but then they have a bunch of documentation about how explicitly CYPRESS COMMANDS ARE NOT PROMISES!!!) that makes it that weird "asynchronous but synchronous" hybrid. Saying the code is "asynchronous" vs. plain synchronous JS is usually a simple enough explanation :)

Comment: Yeah, the thing that usually trips me up mentally when someone refers to Cypress commands as asynchronous is that you don't actually need to do any of the stuff you'd normally need to do with asynchronous code.  Namely, it's not potentially going to fire off at an arbitrary, possibly inconvenient time in the future, and therefore you have to write your code to expect such possibilities.

Comment: Not sure the characterization "fire off at an arbitrary time" is accurate. For example `window.fetch()` fires off immediately - it's the response time that is arbitrary. Same can be said of Cypress commands in general, since it might have to retry.

Comment: So, ***Cypress commands are asynchronous*** is accurate IMO.

Answer (score 5):

The `localstorage` object is the same for all windows in the browser, it doesn't matter if you use `window` or `cy.window()`.

```js
cy.clearCookies();
cy.clearLocalStorage()
  .then(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('One', 'NL');
    window.localStorage.setItem('Two', 'NL');
    window.localStorage.setItem('Three', 'NL');
  })

cy.visit('/')
  .then(() => {
    const myItemOne = window.localStorage.getItem('One');
    const myItemTwo = window.localStorage.getItem('Two');
    const myItemThree = window.localStorage.getItem('Three');
    expect([myItemOne, myItemTwo, myItemThree]).to.deep.equal(['NL','NL','NL'])
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the Cypress commands are queued up to be run later, but the non-Cypress commands are run immediately.  Since the `window.localStorage.setItem` statements are not Cypress commands, they are executed before the Cypress command enqueued by `cy.clearLocalStorage()` is executed.

Per the [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/table-of-contents#Commands):

> Cypress commands don't do anything at the moment they are invoked, but rather enqueue themselves to be run later.

Moving the local storage modifying statements into a Cypress command will allow you to run the statement after the local storage is cleared.

```javascript
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.clearLocalStorage();
  cy.clearCookies();
  cy.window().then((win) => {
    win.localStorage.setItem('One', 'NL');
    win.localStorage.setItem('Two', 'NL');
    win.localStorage.setItem('Three', 'NL');
  });
  visitPage('/');

  cy.window().then((win) => {
    const myItemOne = win.localStorage.getItem('One');
    const myItemTwo = win.localStorage.getItem('Two');
    const myItemThree = win.localStorage.getItem('Three');
    cy.log(myItemOne, myItemTwo, myItemThree);
  });
```